# cfindex custom fields that are used for display no indexible

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfsearch, cfindex

Currently working with Coldfusion 10 and cfsearch.

After many hours of trial and error, I have managed to get cfindex to collect all my custom field data so that it is available to me as fields for the output on my search results page.

My only issue now, is that the search will be able to search for things like true / false strings and it will return in the search results.

I could run a QoQ to strip those out, im just wondering if anyone has any suggestions for adding fields to an index but not having them searchable.

Any ideas greatly appreciated

my current code is below

```
<cftry>
<!-- create new searchable collection -->
<!--- cfcollection action= "create" collection="testsearch" path= "#expandPath('/assets/scripts/server/solr/')#" ---->

    <cfcollection action= "list" name="collectionlist">
    <cfdump var="#collectionlist#">

    <cfquery name="MyQuery" datasource="#request.DSN#" maxrows="10">
    SELECT *
    FROM Store_products
    </cfquery>
    <cfdump var="#myQuery#">

<cfset myAttr = structNew()>
<cfset variables.columns = "COST,CREATEDDATE,CUSTOM_MESSAGE,CUSTOM_MESSAGE_LENGTH,DISPLAYNAME,DONTINCLUDEINSTOCKUPDATE,FEATUREDPRODUCT,FINALDAYS,FREEDELIVERY,HEIGHT,HTMLMETADESCRIPTION,HTMLMETAKEYWORDS,IMAGE1,IMAGE10,IMAGE2,IMAGE3,IMAGE4,IMAGE5,IMAGE6,IMAGE7,IMAGE8,IMAGE9,ISBUNDLE,ISNEWPRODUCT,ISONLINE,ISONSALE,ISSILENT,LONGDESCRIPTION,MANUFACTURER,NOVOUCHERS,ONLINEEXCLUSIVE,PARTNUMBER,PRICE,PRICELEVEL1,PRICELEVEL10,PRICELEVEL11,PRICELEVEL12,PRICELEVEL13,PRICELEVEL14,PRICELEVEL15,PRICELEVEL2,PRICELEVEL3,PRICELEVEL4,PRICELEVEL5,PRICELEVEL6,PRICELEVEL7,PRICELEVEL8,PRICELEVEL9,PRODUCTCATEGORY,PRODUCTCOLOR,PRODUCTMATERIAL,PRODUCTNAME,PRODUCTSIZE,PRODUCTSTYLE,PRODUCTTITLE,PRODUCTVIEWS,RRP,SALEEND,SALEPRICE,SALESTART,SHORTDESCRIPTION,SOLDOUT,STOCKQUANTITY,STORESORTORDER,TAXEXEMPT,VOLUME,WEIGHT,WIDTH">
<cfloop from="1" to="#ListLen(variables.columns,',')#" index="idx">
    <cfset myAttr[listGetAt(variables.columns,idx,',') & "_s"] = listGetAt(variables.columns,idx,',') >
</cfloop>

<cfindex attributecollection="#myAttr#" action="update" collection="testsearch" type="custom" body="DISPLAYNAME,HTMLMETADESCRIPTION,HTMLMETAKEYWORDS,LONGDESCRIPTION,MANUFACTURER,PARTNUMBER,PRODUCTNAME,PRODUCTTITLE,RRP,SHORTDESCRIPTION" query="MyQuery" key= "productname">

<cfsearch name="searchResults" collection="testsearch" criteria="false" >
<cfdump var="#searchResults#">



<cfcatch type="any">
    <cfdump var="#cfcatch#">
</cfcatch>
</cftry>
```